# Select the most recent 5 rows based on date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I haven't touched PHP in a while and trying to select the 5 most recent entries in my database and print them to screen.

I see mysql command isn't recommended anymore and to use PDO->mysql instead.

My query is something like this:

```
SELECT id,title,date,author FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;
```

I'm assuming I would have to put the values into an array and create a loop and output the results.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbhost='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass);

while () {
  print($title[$i], $date[$i], $author[$i]);
  $i++
}

$db = null;

?>
```

I'm stuck filling in the gaps with the above code.

Update: The $db = new PDO.... line is reporting an error message:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket... in /var/...
```

PDO is confirmed to be installed and enabled. My other web apps on the server can connect to the same remote mysql server fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; $db = 'db-name'; $user = 'db-user'; $pw = 'db-password';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $user, $pw);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT id,title,date,author FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$totalRows = $query->rowCount();
?>

<?php do {
// print your results here ex: next line
echo 'Title: '.$row['title'].' Date: '.$row['date'].' Author: '.$row['author'].'<br>'; 
} while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ?>
```

Don't forget to close and release resources

```
<?php $query->closeCursor(); ?>
```

**EDIT**

I recommend not echoing error messages once you have confirmed your code functions as expected; however if you want to simply use plain text you can do this...

You can add this to your connection block...

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Database Connection Failed");
    exit;
}
```

You can also change your query block...

```
try {
    $sql = "SELECT id,title,date,author FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $totalRows = $query->rowCount();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Could not get the data you requested");
    exit;
}
```

Again, it is recommended that errors not be echoed. Use error checking **only** for debugging.

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to get my PHP application to connect to the remote mysql server. I get a PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught exception PDOException with message SQLSTATE Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket...  I don't understand why when my $dbhost is the IP of the remote db server.

Comment: Most systems use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' to connect.

Comment: I can connect fine with mysqli_connect or new mysqli but not PDO.

Comment: What is your msqli connection string?

Comment: $db = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

Comment: 10.x.x.x - its a local IP of another server

Comment: According to your edit you are trying to use this in your connection string `'mysql:dbhost='.$dbhost.'` that is incorrect it should be `'mysql:host='.$dbhost.'`

Comment: Ah, that's it!  Also, what is this line: `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: That shows the error that you received earlier. Without it you would have never been able to debug why the connection was failing

Comment: Gotcha. Is there a way I can just display "Connection to database failed" to visitors? I have php_errors being logged to a log file for review.

Comment: Also - I currently only have one row and it's printing two rows.

Comment: Are you using the loop I provided in my answer or a modified version? The code I provided will only echo what exists in the database based on the query.

Comment: I removed the do and just used the while and it works fine! Thanks SO much for your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$db = PDO('mysql:dbhost=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname', $user, $pass);
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id,title,date,author FROM table ORDER BY date LIMIT 5");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
?>
```

in a loop:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    echo $row['column'];
}
```

From the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I had to keep the $db = new PDO otherwise I had an undefined function error. Now I'm unable to connect to the remote server 'Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message SQLSTATE[HY000] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket...

Comment: Have you got PDO driver installed on your machine? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Comment: PDO is available and installed.